# loop through strings as objects for ggplot

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I'd like to write a loop to generate multiple plots in ggplot. However, a loop iterates through column names as strings, when ggplot accepts object names.

For example:

```
#generate data for df1
a1 <- rnorm(100, 3, 1.2)
b1 <- rnorm(100, 2, 0.5)
c1 <- rnorm(100, 4, 1.5)
d1 <- rnorm(100, 5, 0.2)
e1 <- rnorm(100, 6, 0.7)
df_1 <- data.frame(a1, b1, c1, d1, e1)

#generate data for df2
a2 <- rnorm(50, 3, 1.2)
b2 <- rnorm(50, 2, 0.5)
c2 <- rnorm(50, 4, 1.5)
d2 <- rnorm(50, 5, 0.2)
e2 <- rnorm(50, 6, 0.7)
df_2 <- data.frame(a2, b2, c2, d2, e2)

#rename columns
df_1 <- dplyr::rename(df_1, 
                    a = a1,
                    b = b1,
                    c = c1,
                    d = d1,
                    e = e1)

df_2 <- dplyr::rename(df_2, 
                     a = a2,
                     b = b2,
                     c = c2,
                     d = d2,
                     e = e2)

#create variable name vector to iterate through
vars <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

#loop to generate ggplots
for (var in vars){
  plot_name <- ggplot(df_1, aes(var, color = "df 1")) +
    geom_density() +
    geom_density(var, color="df 2"), data = df_2)

  ggsave(paste0(var, ".pdf"), 
         plot = plot_name,
         width = 8, height = 5, 
         units = "in", 
         dpi = 300)  
}
```

Any idea how I can correctly run this loop?

Comment: Have a look at [aes_string](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html)

Comment: Just replace `aes()` with `aes_string()` in the call to `ggplot()` as well as adding `aes_string()` around `var` in the second `geom_density()`

Comment: also wierd `)` in `geom_density(var, color="df 2"), data = df_2)`

Comment: That works well for ggplot. Is there a more generalizable solution for to iterate through strings as objects when working outside of ggplot?

Comment: You might try using `assign(variable.name, value)` and `get(varname.as.string)`